# I make a side pull-down menu. Does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I make a side pull-down menu. Does not work. Please tell me what the problem is
The menu does not open and does not display any errors. I have already tried everything that I could and zero result.

```js
function left_menu(selector){
  let menu = $(selector);
  let button = menu.find('.left_menu_button');
  let links = menu.find('.left_menu_link');
  let overlay = menu.find('.left_menu_close_container');

  button.on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loggleMenu();
  });

  links.on('click', () => loggleMenu());
  overlay.on('click', () => loggleMenu());

  function loggleMenu(){
    menu.toggleClass('left_menu_main_div_active');

    if(menu.hasClass('left_menu_main_div_active')){
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }else{
        $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
    }
  }
}

left_menu('.left_menu_main_div');
```

```css
.left_menu_button{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 30;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.left_menu_button:hover .left_menu_span{
  background-color: black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.left_menu_button:hover .left_menu_span::after{
  background-color: black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: 2px;

}
.left_menu_button:hover .left_menu_span::before{
  background-color: black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.left_menu_span,
.left_menu_span::after,
.left_menu_span::before{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #1f1a1e;
}
.left_menu_span{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.left_menu_span::before{
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
}
.left_menu_span::after{
  content: '';
  top: 10px;
}
.left_menu_main_div_active .left_menu_span{
  background-color: transparent;
}
.left_menu_main_div_active .left_menu_span::before{
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.left_menu_main_div_active .left_menu_span::after{
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.left_menu_nav{
  padding-top: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left: -100%;
}
.left_menu_main_div_active .left_menu_nav{
  left: 0;
}
.left_menu_link{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.left_menu_link:hover{
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
.left_menu_close_container{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.left_menu_main_div_active .left_menu_close_container{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left_menu_container">
  <div class="left_menu_main_div">
    <a href="#" class="left_menu_button">
      <span class="left_menu_span"></span>
    </a>
    <nav class="left_menu_nav">
      <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Инвентарь</a>
      <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Персонаж</a>    
      <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Ремесло</a>    
      <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Охота</a>    
    </nav>
    <div class="left_menu_close_container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely you forgot to include the jQuery lib...

Comment: @VXp - JQ is included in the code of the question.

Comment: Yeah, because I've added it...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `function loggleMenu(` be `function ToggleMenu(`?

Also where are you loading the script in the html?

Pop a few `console.Log()` calls into the script and see where it gets up to or fails.